# Getting a TypeError while creating odd even checker

Tags: python

so basically this is my code, it's supposed to check if num is divisible by 4 and and 2 and print that out. If not it should only check if even or odd. If the user inputs a string instead of int it gives a different message.

```
    num = (input("number:"""))
try:
    val= int(num)
    if int(num % 2)== 0 and int(num % 4)== 0:
        print("this number is even and divisible by 4!")
    elif (num % 2 == 0):
        print("this number is even")
    else:
        print("this number is odd")
except ValueError:
    print("bro just put a number")
```

I do realise while creating this that I could solve it by just checking if the number is a multiple of 4 with a single statement as it will always be even so checking if it is also divisible by 2 is redundant. However I'm more interested as to why I'm getting an error.

Error:

```
dario@Darios-MacBook-Pro Coding % /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/dario/Desktop/Coding/test.py
number:5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dario/Desktop/Coding/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    if int(num % 2)== 0 and int(num % 4)== 0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: After converting string "num" to int "val" you should work with "val" instead of "num".

Comment: Either use val variable or take input in int 
num = int((input("number:""")))

Comment: use num= int(num) instead of val= int(num)

Comment: _while creating this I could solve it by just checking if the number is a multiple of 4 with a single statement_ - `6` is even but is not divisible by `4`.

Comment: @ack no but instead of if int(num % 2)== 0 and int(num % 4)== 0: you could just put if int(num%4)==0: and it would be divisible by 4 it would always be even so no need for the double statement. After that you could still check for the 'elif (num % 2 == 0):'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is there a way to check if the user did indeed input an `int` instead of string without converting "num" to "val"?*

`str.isdigit()` returns `True` if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, `False` otherwise.

```py
while True:
    inp = input('number: ')
    if inp.isdigit():
        if int(inp) % 2:
            print(f'{inp} is odd')
        else:
            if not (int(inp) % 4):
                print(f'{inp} is divisible by 4')
            else:
                print(f'{inp} is even')
    else:
        print('bro just put a number')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the `num` value, use `int(num)` instead of `int(num % 2) == 0` or just replace `num` with `val`.

At the end you will have this:

```py
num = (input("number: """))
try:
    val = int(num)
    if val % 2 == 0 and val % 4 == 0:
        print("this number is even and divisible by 4!")
    elif (val % 2 == 0):
        print("this number is even")
    else:
        print("this number is odd")
except ValueError:
    print("bro just put a number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your code again. You have defined

`val= int(num)`

But you never use the val variable in your code.

Comment: Thanks! this fixed it. Is there a way to check if the user did indeed input a int instead of string without converting "num" to "val"? I got this "try:" solution from another post, that's why I didn't exactly know what it did.

Answer (score 0):

So I just fixed it with help of the comments, since I converted string "num" to int "val" I had to then use "val" for the statements.

```
   num = (input("number:"""))
try:
    val= int(num)
    if int(val % 2)== 0 and int(val% 4)== 0:
        print("this number is even and divisible by 4!")
    elif (val % 2 == 0):
        print("this number is even")
    else:
        print("this number is odd")
except ValueError:
    print("bro just put a number")
```

This is the working code.

Answer (score 0):

put the input() function inside the try... except... block, and convert the input value direct with `int(input("number: "))`

`````
try:
    num = int(input("number: "))
    if num % 4 == 0:
        print("this number is even and divisible by 4!")
    elif num % 2 == 0:
        print("this number is even")
    else:
        print("this number is odd")
except ValueError:
    print("bro just put a number")````
`````